# Model relationship "User has different Roles per Organization"

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to achieve the following with JPA: I have Users, Organizations and Roles. A User can have multiple Roles in a given Organization. He can also belong to multiple Organizations, and of course have different Roles per Organization.

Currently I would think that a schema for this should look like this (but also open to alternative aproaches):

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
);

CREATE TABLE role
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
);

CREATE TABLE organization
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
);

CREATE TABLE `user_and_organization_to_role`
(
    `id`              INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fk_user`         INT NOT NULL REFERENCES user (id),
    `fk_organization` INT NOT NULL REFERENCES organization (id),
    `fk_role`         INT NOT NULL REFERENCES role (id),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`fk_user`, `fk_organization`, `fk_role`)
);
```

I wouldn't have problems checking roles with native SQL Queries, but I would like to model this in JPA to use the Hibernate Metamodel and Criteria API to implement permission checks.

I thought that something like this would be achievable, even though I'm not 100% sure if I'll reach my goal with Criteria API then:

```
@Entity
public class Organization {
}

@Entity
public class Role {
}

@Entity
public class User {
    private Map<Organization, List<Role>> organizationToRoles;
}
```

Unfortunately I didn't manage to find a way for the correct annotation, so organizationToRoles is mapped correctly. And even though I would think that is a common problem I didn't find a tutorial that explains how to do this.

Could somebody tell me if such a map is doable with JPA at all, and maybe give an example?

Or if it is not possible to directly have a `Map<Organization, List<Role>> organizationToRoles` in `User`, how a mapping could be achived, e.g. with an intermediate Entity that forms the relation between User, Organization and Roles?

Comment: How about creating 1 more entity. `Map<Organization , List<Role>>` looks very complicated for simple entity mapping.

Comment: Org has a list of roles and a list of users. roles have a list orgs and a list of users, users have a list of orgs and a list of roles. Done

Comment: @Toerktumlare `A User can have multiple Roles in a given Organization`, implies that he has different roles for each `Organization`. So it's not that easy.

Comment: according to [that](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.3/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/collection/internal/PersistentMap.java#L285) HBN does not support such mapping: it assumes that row represents single (k,v) pair. In regard to domain model, why do not make independent entity (it already has id!), say, `OrgAuthority` and map it to user as list (you may write a method which lazily transforms list to transient map) - what benefits do you expect from that mapping?

Comment: Using a `Map<Organization, List<Role>>` just seemed "natural" to me, but I wasn't sure if it is possible. :)

@Toerktumlare Unfortunately that doesn't fit my needs, but thanks for the comment :)

@AndreyB.Panfilow Thanks for the comment, I'll try it with an extra Entity, I think I'll try with a `UserAndOrganizationToRole` Entity and a User has a Set of those linked.